# How to find out how much of the circumference of a given circle is covered by other intersecting circles?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, geometry

I have a circle given with center coordinates and radius.

There are also other circles in the plane with known position and the same radius.

How can I find out the part of the circumference of the given circle that is covered by the other circles in the plane with Matlab?

Comment: It a bit confusing. Can you elaborate, maybe an image?

Comment: If the centers of two circles are closer that 2*radius than one of them occlude the other. Will you be able to tell which one is "on top" of the other?

Comment: @AnderBiguri I had to read it twice but then I actually understood it. The question is good. More about algorithms than programming. To make it clearer I improved it to upvote worthy standard.

Comment: @Trilarion ye,yes the question is good! Just proposing some ways of making it clearer. People tend to walk away from questions that need a second deep read.

Answer (score 4):

The general approach would be:

1. Represent the circumference as an interval of an angle [0, 2Pi] representing the angles (towards an arbitrary direction, say x-direction) that are covered by a part of the circumference
2. The current covered circumference is the empty interval [0,0]
3. Compute the circumference that is covered by your circle and one other circle (no covered circumference if there is no intersection, see below)
4. Merge this interval with the current covered circumference in order to obtain a new currently covered circumference, you may get a set of intervals
5. Check if the currently covered circumference is the single interval [0, 2Pi], if not repeat with 3.

And how to calculate the part of the circumference covered by your circle and one other circle?

1. Calculate the intersection points by equalling the circle equation (r²=(x-center_x)²+(y-center_y)²) of both circles and solving the binomial equation. If there are not two intersections points (i.e. <2 solutions) continue with next other circle.
2. That should give you two possible intervals on your circle. In order to find out which one is correct, take one point in each interval, i.e. one point on each part of the circumference and check the distance to the other circle (must be < radius). This is the part of the circumference that is covered.

You may return earlier with the result that the total circumference is covered but if not you will have to test every other circle.

It only works because the radii of all circles are equal. If the other circles could be smaller it's also still okay, but if they could be larger, you do not get always intersection points, making the whole problem much more difficult. But you said, this is not the case here.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot give much actual Matlab, only the outline of the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

As explained by Trilarion, at the heart of the computation you need to intersect two circles.
You can find code for this all over the web, or write your own. One source is *[Computational Geometry in C](http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/books/compgeom.html)*, the code associated with 2D robot arm motion (`arm.c`), which includes functions to intersect two circles. There are degenerate cases that must be handled carefully: two circles intersecting in just one point, or equal circles intersecting in a full circle.

Answer (score 1):

to put things in perspective, you can use matlab pde to show us figures

`pdecirc(1,2,3)`

`pdecirc(-1,-1,2)`

If you want to plot it on matlab using equations, it is :

`n = 100                           % Resolution`

`angle = 0:2*pi/n:2*pi;            % vector of angles at which points are drawn`
`R = 3;                            % radius`

`x = R*cos(angle)+2;  y = R*sin(angle)+1;   % Coordinates of the circle`
`plot(x,y);                        % Plot the circle`

`axis equal;`
`grid on;`

and you can plot as many as you like, you might have to set n to high value if you want very high resolution. Now on to your question..
use matlab circcirc to find the intersects of your circles, see http://uk.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/circcirc.html for more details

`[xout,yout] = circcirc(1,2,3,-1,-1,2); %which returns the x-intersects and the y-intersects`

you can group the x and y intersect and do calculation of circumference based on the radius and the intersects. If you don't know how, check this http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/QQ/database/QQ.09.07/h/michelle3.html
Say you have 2 circles centred at (1,2) and (-1,-1)

`i = pdist([xout(1),yout(1);xout(2),yout(2)],'euclidean') %distance between intersects`

`P = [xout(1),yout(1);1,2]  %coordinate of one of the intersections and your centre`

`E = pdist(P,'euclidean')`

`y = asin(i/(2*E))*2 %angle of your arc`

`cir = pi*2*R1*(y/(2*pi))`  %ratio of your arc times the total circumference

This should give you your answer between 2 circles, unless my math from highschool fails me.

PS: the good thing about using circcirc is that if the circles do not intersect (i.e overlap or not touching each other, it returns NaNs for your coordinate, which you can then process)